# Does heating potato starch destroy its resistant starch?

Tags: heat, food-chemistry

Resistant starch, as found in potato starch, is supposed to have [health benefits](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/resistant-starch-101). There are differing opinions on whether or not heating potato starch destroys the resistant starch in it and thereby also the supposed health benefits. I would like to know what the scientific **consensus** is.

That reheating potato starch **destroys** its resistant starch, is argued by:

- [Marks Daily Apple](https://www.marksdailyapple.com/resistant-starch-your-questions-answered/)

> Any idea if heating the potato starch (like using it as a thickening agent in soups/stews) negates its RS function? Yes, the RS will be completely negated.

- [Diabetes Sister](https://diabetessisters.org/article/why-resistant-starch-matters)

> If potato starch is heated it converts to normal starch and you will get none of the amazing benefits.

- [Mark Hyman](https://drhyman.com/blog/2016/03/24/the-starch-that-makes-you-lean-and-healthy/)

> Resistant starch is made by cooking and then cooling starches like potatoes or rice and not reheating them, transforming regular starch into resistant starch.

- [Healthline](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/9-foods-high-in-resistant-starch#5.-Raw-potato-starch)

> It’s important to not heat the potato starch. Instead, prepare the meal and then add the potato starch once the dish has cooled.

That reheating potato starch **does not destroy** its resistant starch, is argued by:

- [John Hopkins](https://hopkinsdiabetesinfo.org/what-is-resistant-starch/)

> Reheating doesn’t decrease the amount of resistant starch.

- [Bernard Preston](https://www.bernard-preston.com/Reheating-resistant-starch.html)

> Carbs, cooked and then cooled, and again reheated, pass through the small intestine into the colon as resistant starch where they are instead fermented by the healthy probiotic bacteria; instead of forming simple sugars with all the potential problems of obesity, diabetes and glucose intolerance.

- [Chris Kresser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N812i6gaPKM)

> Each heating and cooling cycle adds more resistant starch.

There also appear to be [different types of resistant starches](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/resistant-starch-101#types), which might complicate the discussion in ways I do not know.

Comment: The concepts are review in this paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3823506/

Answer (score 4):

"The amylose–amylopectin ratio determines how much retrograded starch remains on reheating, with retrograded amylose being more heat stable than retrograded amylopectin. "

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7984060/

For the love of god, don't depend on sites like Hyman or Mark's Daily Apple for answers.

Comment: I agree with the general sentiment of this answer, but we usually use a less colourful language to express this. On another matter: we usually do not answer questions with a single quote, but I really think it is fine in this context.

Comment: Thanks Martin, point taken!  I'll do better if I ever leave another comment.

Answer (score 0):

The original quotes don't distinguish between the 5 types of resistant starch, but from this blog community back when this was first discussed, I know they are referring to RS2 potato starch as supplied by Bob's Red Mill in their "Unmodified Potato Starch" product. Potato starch is extracted from cold potatoes and spray dried at low heat which does preserve the RS2 resistant starch. Heating destroys the RS2 starch and turns it in digestible (by humans) carbohydrate. The equivalent RS2 source from whole foods would be raw potato.
The accepted answer is referring to RS3 starch from cooked and cooled starch where starch retrogradation during cooling partially forms a new resistant starch but that is not the RS2 type found in raw starches.
People get confused between the 2 types since they can both come from potatoes. All 5 types RS1-RS5 are presented in WikiPedia. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistant_starch. Heating losses are mentioned under the section on isolated starch.
In the original question, the Kresser and Preston quotes are referring to RS3 so that requires heating and cooling to form retrograded starch. The Hopkins article mis-interprets their source and only is talking heating in regard to RS3. Their source ( Patterson MA, Maiya M, Stewart ML:  Resistant Starch Content in Foods Commonly Consumed in the United States: A Narrative Review. J Acad Nutr Diet 2020 Feb; 120 (2): 230-244. PMID: 32040399.) only includes data from cooked potatoes because raw potato starch was excluded. From their source "Exclusion criteria included the use of RS from flours or
starches, isolated raw starch, or uncooked foods unsuitable
for consumption (eg, raw potatoes and raw cassava)".
The Hyman quote is referring to RS3 but the linked article talks more about RS2 potato starch used in smoothies and kept cold.
Hope this helps.
Naja's source in her comment clearly states that RS2 as in raw potato starch is degraded by heat. Her answer only applies to the RS3 type.
Sorry I could post a potential answer but could not post this as a comment to the previous answer because I just signed up. Again apologies.

Comment: Formatting guides for [texts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and [formulas/equations/expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).